# Error: Wildfly dead but pid file exists

Tags: linux, wildfly

When I tried to restart wildfly webserver it kept giving these errors

```
 Stopping wildfly: kill: usage: kill [-s sigspec | -n signum | -sigspec] pid |     jobspec ... or kill -l [sigspec]
 /etc/init.d/wildfly: line 142: [: -eq: unary operator expected
 /etc/init.d/wildfly: line 142: [: -eq: unary operator expected
 /etc/init.d/wildfly: line 142: [: -eq: unary operator expected
 /etc/init.d/wildfly: line 142: [: -eq: unary operator expected
```

When I tried to check the status by

```
sudo service wildfly status
```

The output is:

```
wildfly dead but pid file exists
```

seems like I need to delete PID file so that I can restart it.

Comment: The init.d script is broken. But it's hard to tell how broken without seeing it. Which operating system (a.k.a. distribution) is it? Which version? From where did you install WildFly? Which version? And also, do you still run sysv-initd or have you already switched to systemd?

Comment: I tried `service wildfyy restart 1` it seems to work now. I will check out the server logs to see if it starts smoothly or not

Answer (score 1):

I had to delete the /run/wildfly/wildfly.pid and start the service again. For me this was because the system crashed.